# Stationary time-series and N-order stationarity

Tags: time-series, stationarity

Suppose I have a stationary time series, does this imply that the series is also N-order stationary?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. Stationary is not a term that is used very rigorously in every text book. Especially in the context of time series usually people are referring to wide sense stationarity. When people say strictly stationary then they mean stationarity of all orders.

Comment: *All orders* only in the sense of those for which moments of the distribution exist. My answer contains an example where *all orders* are limited below unity.

Comment: A belated +1. You are perfectly correct in what you say and @RichardHardy's claim is wrong.